# Example 1.30 from Introduction to Mathematical Thinking by John D'Angelo

Tags: quadratics

[image]

I understand the example. However, I am curious how the author knows to start the argument with $$(1-\lvert x\rvert)^2\ge0.$$ What algorithm does he follow that begins with this assumption?

Comment: The cheap method employed by any show off, starting by what you want to prove, apply equivalences and then write the equivalences in the opposite order. You can synthesize the argument by solving the problem: For what $y$ does $f(x)=y$ has a solution? You get a quadratic equation, and the condition on its discriminant being non-negative gives you an inequality $|y|\leq 1/2$.

Comment: $(1-|x|)^2 \ge 0 \implies  1 + x^2 - 2|x|\ge0 \implies \frac {1+x^2}{2} \ge |x|$

Comment: The funny thing is that the direct approach is way faster than all that mess that they did there with proving that the image contains $[-1/2,1/2]$ and it is contained in it. The whole beginning of that proof was a waste of time.

Comment: The proof is: $y$ is such that $f(x)=y$ has a solution iff $y=x/(1+x^2)$ has a solution. This is equivalent to $yx^2-x+y=0$ having a solution. This is equivalent to the discriminant $1-4y^2$ being non-negative. Finally, this is equivalent to $-1/2\leq y\leq 1/2$. Done. An author that gets tangled so much in such a basic problem, in a book called 'Mathematical Thinking' is a questionable example to follow. My advice, learn mathematical thinking from some other source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to "guess" it would be to first note that the function is odd i.e. $\,f(-x)=-f(x)\,$, and therefore it is enough to prove the inequality for $\,x \ge 0\,$. But in that case $\,|x| = x \ge 0\,$, so:

$$
\dfrac{x}{1+x^2} \le \dfrac{1}{2} \;\;\iff\;\; 2x \le 1 + x^2 \;\;\iff\;\; 0 \le 1-2x+x^2 = (1-x)^2
$$

Now that you have the "clue" figured out, dress it up as $\,\left(1-|x|\right)^2\,$ to account for negative $x$'s, then plug it all the way back into the original statement, without any hint whatsoever of how you got it, and it suddenly looks like a bit of black magic ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical thinking doesn't always come from an algorithm.  Also, you shouldn't assume that just because the author wrote $(1-|x|)^2 \geq 0$, it was the first thing that popped into his head.  When you write a proof, often it comes together in bits and pieces.  You might start at the beginning and see where your guesses take you, or you might jump to the end and see what it takes to get there.

But here's a rule of thumb which the author may be relying on: it's been said that all inequalities can be derived from the fact that for all real $a$, $a^2 \geq 0$.   The author has used this fact, substituting $a = 1-|x|$.